# Flutter TextField obscure text: show last letter

Tags: flutter

I have a flutter app with a password textfield, where I want to obscure the text like this:

```
TextFormField(
  obscureText: true,
  enableSuggestions: false,
  autocorrect: false,
)
```

Now, when I run the app on iOS, the password is fully obscured. When I run the app on Android, the password is obscured, but it shows the last letter for a while, like this:

[image]

I want to have that functionality on iOS as well. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you have to use custom `TextEditingController` and remove  `obscureText: true`. Custom controller should be as following...

```
class ObscuringTextEditingController extends TextEditingController {
  @override
  TextSpan buildTextSpan({required BuildContext context, required bool withComposing, TextStyle? style }) {
    var displayValue = '•' * value.text.length;
    if (!value.composing.isValid || !withComposing) {
      return TextSpan(style: style, text: displayValue);
    }
    final TextStyle? composingStyle = style?.merge(
      const TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.underline),
    );
    return TextSpan(
      style: style,
      children: <TextSpan>[
        TextSpan(text: value.composing.textBefore(displayValue)),
        TextSpan(
          style: composingStyle,
          text: value.composing.textInside(displayValue),
        ),
        TextSpan(text: value.composing.textAfter(displayValue)),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

And your text field should be,

```
TextFormField(
  //obscureText: true,
  enableSuggestions: false,
  autocorrect: false,
  controller: ObscuringTextEditingController(),
)
```

Comment: I tried it. This results in every character being obscured all the time. How can I adapt that so that the last character is not obscured for a duration and then gets obscured as well?

Answer (score 0):

```
`class ObscuringTextEditingController extends TextEditingController {
  bool isObscured = true;

  void changeFieldVisibility({required bool isVisible}) {
    isObscured = !isVisible;
  }

  @override
  TextSpan buildTextSpan({
    required BuildContext context,
    required bool withComposing,
    TextStyle? style,
  }) {
    final displayValue = isObscured
        ? ('•' * (value.text.length - 1)) + (value.text.characters.lastOrNull ?? '')
        : value.text;
    if (!value.composing.isValid || !withComposing) {
      return TextSpan(style: style, text: displayValue);
    }
    final composingStyle = style?.merge(
      const TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.underline),
    );

    return TextSpan(
      style: style,
      children: <TextSpan>[
        TextSpan(text: value.composing.textBefore(displayValue)),
        TextSpan(
          style: composingStyle,
          text: value.composing.textInside(displayValue),
        ),
        TextSpan(text: value.composing.textAfter(displayValue)),
      ],
    );
  }
}`
```

Here is my solution for field visibility

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).